# Multiple sites and application pools in IIS for same application load balancing

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, load-balancing, application-pool

What is the defacto standard or best practice when it comes to increasing throughput and performance for an ASP.NET web service application?

Would there be any performance increase to method 1 below?

1. Utilizing the same directory/code, create multiple websites in IIS bound to different VIPs, all running on different application pools.  Then use a network load-balancer to balance between the VIPs
2. Utilizing one website / application pool in IIS bound to one VIP; create additional VM instances and load-balance between the servers
3. Combination of both method 1, and method 2.

Comment: How many physical machines do you have? This sounds like a strategy for robustness (if 1 app pool recycles, leaves the other ones alone), but if you only have X cpu's it doesn't matter how you slice it.

Comment: We're still determining the infrastructure; it will be all virtualized.  Main thing, I wasn't sure if there was any performance gain from having the multiple applications pools / sites on different IP's on the same server.